# How execute the Mongodb shell script in visual studio code editor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, visual-studio, mongodb-query

How to execute the mongodb script ie Java script in Visual studio code ?
For your information : Currently i am using  Robo 3T 1.1 for  execute the mongodb query, I am connecting mongodb using given below information.( Mongo db not installed in machine.)

```
Host name:king302.hcare.comm
Port:27017
username:mycon123
password:*******
database:studdb
```

I am planning to write the Java script or Mongodb shell script  in visual studio code editor since its user friendly . So can anyone help how to write the code and execute it via visual studio code editor ?

Example code :

```
function checkGender(studentId){
   var result=db.student.find({"studentId":studentId});
   if(result.gender=='MALE'){
       print('Its male');
   }
   else if(result.gender=='FEMALE')
    {
      print('its female');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the [javascript code](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#running-js-files-via-a-mongo-shell-instance-on-the-server) via mongo shell in Visual Studio code.

Write all of your [javascript code](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) that connects with mongodb and defines all your function and save it as `mongoScript.js`

Example:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDatabase");
```

In the explorer right click your `mongoScript.js -> Open in Terminal`

In terminal run this script as `mongo mongoScript.js`

You need to make sure that the `mongo` executable is in path ot accessible via command line.

Comment: installed mongodb in local and i connected the remote server using given below comments in mongo shell.                                                          mongo --username test --password test --host test.java.com --port 27017